# Using sort function on array of dynamic ranges in VBA?

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, sorting, range

Have an array of dynamic ranges that need to be sorted by the B1 position in each. I wrote some very long an inefficient code for a bubble sort that breaks occasionally and was wondering if the .Sort function might work. Here's the code that loops in each dynamic range. If there are syntax errors it's because I chopped it out of larger code. I can assure you that everything works up until the .Sort line:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim everything() As Range
Dim check As Range
Dim count As Range

Dim lr As Long
Dim x As Long
Dim y As Long
Dim z As Long
Dim q As Long
With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Names and Vendors")

'Counts how many rows contain data
If .Cells(.Rows.count, "D").End(xlUp).Row > .Cells(.Rows.count, "B").End(xlUp).Row Then
    lr = .Cells(.Rows.count, "D").End(xlUp).Row
    Else
    lr = .Cells(.Rows.count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
    End If

'Step 1: Counts number of RMs to size the "everything" array

For z = 2 To lr
    Set count = .Range("B" & z)
        If IsEmpty(count) = False Then
            count.Select
            q = q + 1
            End If
    Next z
    ReDim everything(q - 1) As Range 'Resizes array

'Step 2: Loops all RM info into array by each distinct range

For x = 2 To lr
    Set check = .Range("A" & x & ":Q" & x)

        'ensures subcomponents are added to range
        If IsEmpty(.Range("B" & 1 + x)) = True Then
            Do While IsEmpty(.Range("B" & 1 + x)) = True And x < lr
                Set check = Union(check, .Range("A" & 1 + x & ":Q" & 1 + x))
                check.Select
                x = x + 1
            Loop
        End If
    Set everything(y) = check
    y = y + 1
    check.Select
Next x

'This doesn't work. Is there a way to make it work?
everything.Sort Key1:=Range("B1"), Order1:=xlAscending, MatchCase:=False

End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi Poppenhoffer, off topic but you still got quite some loose ends on your other questions (8 questions, zero accepted answers). Please address this too.

Comment: Try  applying `.Sort` on one `Range` instead of an array of ranges, like `everything(1).Sort`

Comment: And do not try sorting noncontiguous ranges.

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't clear. I have this range array where the name of each range is contained in the 0, 1 position of each respective range, but the number of columns that contains accompanying data in each range is dynamic. I want to be able to sort each range relative to each other range by the cell in each that contains the respective range's name using the .Sort function. I wrote a bubble sort, but it's pretty slow. As far as I can tell, I can't use that .Sort function to do this.